# Validation is failing in Aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

So I have set a basic validation for when required is set everything seems on the up and up but when I actually return is false as shown on the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:availableForFlowScreens/documentation) all I get is the error below.

An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow

> An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow. Please
> contact your system administrator for more information.

Specifically though if I look in the logs I get the error.

> Flow encountered an error when processing and converting between data
> types. Please check the flow and ensure all data types are matched
> correctly.

I am on a sandbox for summer'21 is there any change I've totally missed that might be causing this? for completeness see my validation code below this is called from the init function.

```
cmp.set('v.validate', function() {
    var userInput = cmp.get('v.selected');
    var userInputLength = userInput.length;
    var required = cmp.get('v.required');
    if (required && userInput && userInputLength > 0) {
        // If the component is valid...
        return {
            isValid: true
        };
    } else {
        // If the component is invalid...
        return {
            isValid: false,
            errorMessage: 'A value is required.'
        };
    }
})
```

Comment: Please don't tag this as both LWC and Aura. It appears to be Aura, you should be specific.

Comment: And title also :) About the question: error indicates that flow is receiving wrong type probably from the component. There is only one thing different from the example: type of the quotes. You are using double quotes while in the example, single quotes are used. Normally there should not be any difference, but flow engine is really fussy so I would check that, especially having in mind that you didn't mention any issues when input is valid

Comment: @user1974566 I've tried with both single and double quotes same issue

Comment: @sfdcfox Apologies